# context.refresh() and/or Waypoint.refreshAll() not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

**Updated 2/16 with new code to reflect mistake found from comment**

I have waypoints working correctly on a page with the following code. Note that I'm using version 3.1.1 of the plugin, but I'm still using jQuery syntax akin to version 2.x of the plugin to handle some complex selectors. This code IS working:

```
var stickTop = wrapper.waypoint({
    handler: function(direction){         
        var len = $(this.element).closest('.ctable').find('div.ctable-row').length; 
        if ((direction === 'down') && (len > 1)) {
            $(this.element).closest('.ctable').find(stickTarget).addClass('stuck').css("top", $pageHeadOffset );
        }
        else if ((direction === 'up') && (len > 1)) {
            $(this.element).closest('.ctable').find(stickTarget).removeClass('stuck');
        }
    }, 
    offset: $pageHeadOffset,
});
```

This is (still) fine and working correctly, but I have another element on the page that resizes, effectively making the page much longer. To deal with this, I've tried calling `Waypoint.refreshAll();` and `stickTop.context.refresh();` on another click target, like so:

```
$('.page-info-link').click(function(){
    $('.page-info').toggleClass('closed');
    $('.page-info-message').slideToggle();
    Waypoint.refreshAll();
});
```

But I cannot get the refresh to accurately work.

Is there any way to use the above jQuery-like syntax (without passing the element: option and still call the refresh?

**Update 2/16:**

This new code now fires a console error:

```
$('.page-info-link').click(function(){
    $('.page-info').toggleClass('closed')
    $('.page-info-message').slideToggle()
    stickTop.refresh()
});
```

Error: "undefined is not a function"

Comment: Have you tried adding the [debug script](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/debugging/) and looking for if it produces any console errors as you work your way through the page? I believe you have things generally set up right except it looks like you have a fixed position element as a waypoint.

Comment: You're right, I was incorrectly adding fixed position to a waypoint. I've fixed that and am now using the same model you use on the sticky shortcut (there is a wrapped div around the fixed sticky element, which has the same specified height as the sticky element).

Comment: I've updated the original post with the new code, as well as what is throwing the "undefined" error in the console. Doesn't look like the debig script is doing anything now though. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. `stickTop.refresh()`: I'm not sure why you changed this. First, `stickTop` is an array, as `$.fn.waypoint` returns an array of Waypoint instances, one for each matched element in the jQuery object. Second, `refresh` isn't a method on a Waypoint instance, it is a method on a Context. TLDR: Stick with the `Waypoint.refreshAll()`.
2. `slideToggle` is a jQuery animation. What you're trying to do is call refresh after that animation has finished but it's an asynchronous function. By calling `refreshAll` directly after it you're doing the refresh before the animation has even begun. You'll want to call refresh in the `complete` callback of the animation.

End result:

```
$('.page-info-message').slideToggle(function() {
  Waypoint.refreshAll()
})
```

Comment: Ahh, this works! I was definitely forgetting about the asynchronous function. Thanks so much for the support and the great plugin!